# Material-UI Data Grid onSortModelChange Causing an Infinite Loop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm following the Sort Model documentation (https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/sorting/#basic-sorting) and am using `sortModel` and `onSortModelChange` exactly as used in the documentation. However, I'm getting an infinite loop immediately after loading the page (I can tell this based on the console.log).

What I've tried:

- Using useCallback within the onSortChange prop
- Using server side sorting (https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/sorting/#server-side-sorting)
- Using `if (sortModel !== model) setSortModel(model)` within the onSortChange function.

I always end up with the same issue. I'm using Blitz.js.

My code:

useState:

```
const [sortModel, setSortModel] = useState<GridSortModel>([
    {
      field: "updatedAt",
      sort: "desc" as GridSortDirection,
    },
  ])
```

rows definition:

```
  const rows = currentUsersApplications.map((application) => {
    return {
      id: application.id,
      business_name: application.business_name,
      business_phone: application.business_phone,
      applicant_name: application.applicant_name,
      applicant_email: application.applicant_email,
      owner_cell_phone: application.owner_cell_phone,
      status: application.status,
      agent_name: application.agent_name,
      equipment_description: application.equipment_description,
      createdAt: formattedDate(application.createdAt),
      updatedAt: formattedDate(application.updatedAt),
      archived: application.archived,
    }
  })
```

columns definition:

```
  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70, hide: true },
    {
      field: "business_name",
      headerName: "Business Name",
      width: 200,
      // Need renderCell() here because this is a link and not just a string
      renderCell: (params: GridCellParams) => {
        console.log(params)
        return <BusinessNameLink application={params.row} />
      },
    },
    { field: "business_phone", headerName: "Business Phone", width: 180 },
    { field: "applicant_name", headerName: "Applicant Name", width: 180 },
    { field: "applicant_email", headerName: "Applicant Email", width: 180 },
    { field: "owner_cell_phone", headerName: "Ownership/Guarantor Phone", width: 260 },
    { field: "status", headerName: "Status", width: 130 },
    { field: "agent_name", headerName: "Agent", width: 130 },
    { field: "equipment_description", headerName: "Equipment", width: 200 },
    { field: "createdAt", headerName: "Submitted At", width: 250 },
    { field: "updatedAt", headerName: "Last Edited", width: 250 },
    { field: "archived", headerName: "Archived", width: 180, type: "boolean" },
  ]
```

Rendering DataGrid and using sortModel/onSortChange

```
      <div style={{ height: 580, width: "100%" }} className={classes.gridRowColor}>
        <DataGrid
          getRowClassName={(params) => `MuiDataGrid-row--${params.getValue(params.id, "status")}`}
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={10}
          components={{
            Toolbar: GridToolbar,
          }}
          filterModel={{
            items: [{ columnField: "archived", operatorValue: "is", value: showArchived }],
          }}
          sortModel={sortModel}
          onSortModelChange={(model) => {
            console.log(model)
            //Infinitely logs model immediately
            setSortModel(model)
          }}
        />
      </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by wrapping `rows` and `columns` in useRefs and used their `.current` property for both of them. Fixed it immediately.

Comment: `useMemo` also worked for me

Comment: can you give some code example, pls?

Answer (score 3):

Could not understand what the top post meant by using useRef, but the below solution   is what worked for me:

```
    const [sortModel, setSortModel] = useState<GridSortModel>([
        {
            field: 'created',
            sort: 'desc',
        },
    ]);

    const handleSortChange = (model: GridSortModel) => {
        /* if statement to prevent the infinite loop by confirming model is 
         different than the current sortModel state */
        if (JSON.stringify(model) !== JSON.stringify(sortModel)) {
            setSortModel(model);
        }
    };

    <DataGrid
    rows={taskData}
    columns={myWorkColumns}
    sortModel={sortModel}
    onSortModelChange={(model) => handleSortChange(model)}
    />
```

Comment: Should be the answer - I know useRef is more React-y :), but this is simple, effective, and has a complete code example. Also works fine if you don't have a default sort order on initial load, and also works for `sortingMode="server"`

Answer (score 0):

experienced this issue also recently. here's how i was able to fix it.

```
handleSortChange = (model) => {
  let dgSort = model[0];
  if (JSON.stringify(this.state.dgSort) !== JSON.stringify(dgSort)){
    console.log("new sort", dgSort);
    this.setState({
      dgSort: dgSort
    });
  }
}
```

For some reason, adding a condition just before setting the state prevents the infinite loop of setting the state over and over. In my understanding, whenever you set the state (or change it), the DataGrid automatically re-renders itself and again re-setting the state hence the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used **useRef** to capture the change of sorting and after call it in the other part of the code.

```
const handleSort = (params: GridSortModel) => {
    const elem = params
    if (params && params.length) {
        sortRows.current = { field_order: `${elem[0].field}`, order: `${elem[0].sort}` }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is the function stops onStateChange to call continuously for DataGrid .
Can have function on comparing filterCount or sortModel : 

    onStateChange={(e) => {
                      if (JSON.stringify(this.state.filteredCountFAGrid) !== JSON.stringify(e.pagination.rowCount)){
                        console.log("new sort", e.pagination.rowCount);
                        this.setState({
                          filteredCountFAGrid: e.pagination.rowCount
                        });
                      }
                    }}
```