# How to wrap MUI data grid rows and columns in useRef (to fix infinite loop in onSortModelChange)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I have the same problem as the question below. A comment said to use useRef to wrap rows and columns and use its .current value. How do I do that??

[Material-UI Data Grid onSortModelChange Causing an Infinite Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004286/material-ui-data-grid-onsortmodelchange-causing-an-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 2):

I could not figure out the useRef, and seeing this post is a month old you have most likely solved it by now. But for others like myself googling for a solution, here is how I solved the problem:

```
    const [sortModel, setSortModel] = useState<GridSortModel>([
    {
        field: 'created',
        sort: 'desc',
    },
]);

const handleSortChange = (model: GridSortModel) => {
    /* if statement to prevent the infinite loop by confirming model is 
     different than the current sortModel state */
    if (JSON.stringify(model) !== JSON.stringify(sortModel)) {
        setSortModel(model);
    }
};

<DataGrid
rows={taskData}
columns={myWorkColumns}
sortModel={sortModel}
onSortModelChange={(model) => handleSortChange(model)}
/>
```